# Using PHP how to round decimal number to ceil

Tags: php

I want to round 5.29 to 5.30,  5.14 to 5.15 how to do that I have tried this many ways but not working

Not working codes;

```
<?php
 echo round(5.29, 2);
 echo round((5.29*100)/100, 2); 
?>
```

please some one help me

Comment: Are you trying to round to the first decimal place or to multiples of 5?

Comment: @user3099298 See the edit to my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you were trying to round a decimal *off* to the nearest 0.05:

```
echo round(5.29 * 2, 1) / 2; // 5.30
echo round(5.14 * 2, 1) / 2; // 5.15
```

**EDIT:** Or if you wanted to round a decimal *up* to the nearest 0.05:

```
echo ceil(5.29 / 0.05) * 0.05; // 5.30
echo ceil(5.14 / 0.05) * 0.05; // 5.15
```

Answer (score 0):

This code may help you

```
 $number=5.24;//number you want to round
 $decimal_part=($number-floor($number))*100;
 echo ceil($decimal_part/5)*5;
```

the above code will give you the required result.
in above code if you give **`5.21`** it will give **`5.25`**.
if you want **`5.21`** to convert into **`5.20`** then change the **`ceil`** to **`round`**

Answer (score -1):

Please use following code

```
  echo (float)round(5.29 * 2, 1) / 2; // returns 5.30
  echo (float)round(5.14 * 2, 1) / 2 // returns 5.15
```